# Why would I be unable to access a pipe method on a Subject?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

When passing in a Subject object to a method I have created I believe that the subject, foo$ as shown below, should have access to a pipe() method due to the class definition of Subject which extends Observable but I have no access to the pipe() method during runtime. The code compiles fine and there is no issue in VSCode.

I have tried using foo$.asObservable() right before the .pipe() but a similar issue happens where I am told at runtime that "foo$.asObservable is not a function". I have also tried casting foo$ to an Observable or Subject because when I log the type of foo$ in this method only "object" is shown.

When using of(foo$) right before the pipe to create an observable this does work, but I no longer have access to the _.change or _.list values which I need in my code below. I have tried to play with this implementation to store those values elsewhere but I have been unable to come up with anything.

```
ngOnInit() {
    super.init();
    const config = super.getCurrentConfig();
    this.model.updateProperties([['graphicName', '/' + config.graphicName]]);
    this.model.updateProperties([['inputs', config.inputs ? config.inputs : []], ['identifier', config.identifer ? config.identifier : '']]);
    this.systemMessageBusService.push(new SystemMessage(SystemMessageAction.GET_THE_FOO, name));
    this.subscriptions.push(
        this.model
        .getProperty('foo$')
        .pipe(filterNotNulls(), distinctUntilChanged())
        .subscribe(_ => this.subscriptionUpdated(_))
    );
}

private subscriptionUpdated(foo$: Subject<ListValue<BarFoo>>) {
    this.model.updateProperty('foosSubscription', foo$
        .pipe(filterNotNulls())
        .subscribe(_ => {
            if (!_.change) {
                this.myClass.doThis(_.list);
            } else {
                this.myClass.doThat(_.change);
            }
        })
    );
}


updateProperty<K extends keyof T>(propertyName: K, value: any) {
    const currentValue: T = Object.assign({}, this.getCurrentValue());
    currentValue[propertyName] = value;
    this.update(currentValue);
}
```

Expected result: I am able to use the .pipe method on my Subject.

Actual result: "foo$.pipe is not a function"

Comment: try calling the asObservable metod before the pipe

Comment: @EduardoVargas I have tried that as well and I receive a similar issue where "ERROR: TypeError ... foo$.asObservable is not a function"

Comment: Will you please post updateProperty?

Comment: @VivekDoshi added

Comment: Can you show us where you declare foo$? Are you importing everything correctly?

Comment: You are passing a `Subscription` object as the `value` to `updateProperty()`. Is that your intention because the code inside that function does not appear to have anything to do with subscriptions.

Comment: @WillAlexander added where the method is called

Comment: @Reactgular the model I am updating has a property called foodSubscription which holds the subscription which I am updating. So you're correct that the code inside does not have anything to do with subscriptions, but it can altar a property which deals with subscriptions.

Comment: I think the simple answer is that `foo$` is not a Subject. If it was, you would be able to pipe it.

Comment: Your `getProperty` call doesn't return a Subject: it returns whatever is emitted by the Observable pipe. If you are trying to emit a Subject…there's a better way to do things.

Comment: @WillAlexander that does make sense that getProperty isn't giving a subject back now that I am looking at it. It strange though coming from other languages that I was even allowed to get to this point in the code with foo$ not coming in as my expected type.

Comment: A decent IDE which has indexed your project will underline that as an error.

Comment: @WillAlexander Do you have a recommendation other than VSCode by any chance?

Comment: WebStorm all the way :)

Comment: @WillAlexander I'll give it a try :) thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getProperty` call is not returning a `Subject` (or any other `Observable`-like, so the rest of the code cannot work. Try simply returning the result of the `pipe` without the `subscribe` call.